# PCM/RAW audio container for streaming

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, pcm

I would like to know if any of you tried to stream RAW audio data. I tried to do that using a WAV file but this does not support streaming. Could anyone provide me a container for that (except Matroska) :)

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "streaming"?

Comment: you can use OpenAL to render LPCM audio once you setup some means to pull a stream onto your device - once you get it working with PCM you will realize you should have started with a compressed format like AAC due to realistic bandwidth limitations even on WiFi say nothing about 3G

Comment: @EventHorizon, You would be surprised what you can get away with these days.  Raw PCM audio data (at something reasonable like 16bit/44.1kHz/stereo) can fit easily in the bandwidth provided by most WiFi connections.  3G is another matter indeed.  He probably has a specific reason for wanting to use PCM.

Comment: @xlogic, Can you expand a bit on what you are streaming to?

Comment: ok, i would like to stream from one server to another some audio data. After what i searched over internet you could achieve that by using OggRAW. RIFF Wav file has a certain structure that you must specify the content lenght. The destination computer is running a player that i can not modify at all, so the only solution it would be to find a format that you can write RAW audio data into it.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered OggPCM. I think is the only container which allows you to stream PCM audio (and quite standard). 
WAV file does not allows you to stream raw data, so I eliminated this one from the list. I wanted to stream some audio data thought in my wireless network, so the bandwidth it was not an issue.